# FancyBox - Reload Parent Page on Button Click

Tags: javascript, user-interface, fancybox

I am using [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to show a page (say child.htm) within another page(parent.htm).

I know how to automatically [reload the parent page after closing the iFrame](http://jsfiddle.net/EWTxv/):

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```

However, my requirement is more specific. I need to close the iframe and then reload the parent page (parent.htm) only when an user clicks on a button (e.g : clicking on button "OK" present in child.htm).

The problem with the code snippet that I'm having is that the parent page is getting reloaded even when I click on the close icon or when I click anywhere outside the frame. This is something that I want to restrict. My agenda is to cause page refresh only on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
  $('.fancybox').fancybox({
      href : 'child.html',
      type : 'iframe',    
      afterShow: function(){     
        $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#button').click(function(){
             // do something
             ...

             // reload parent window and close fancybox
             window.parent.location.reload();
             window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
         }); 
       }
 });
```